# "turn on a single word"?

Tags: meaning

"In fact, Matt says there is a lawsuit going on right now that may turn on a single word - the word and. "

In this sentence, I do not catch the meaning of "turn on a single word."

What does it mean?  More specifically, what does "on" mean there?

Comment: _Turn_ in this case means 'depend'; i.e, the case depends on the meaning of a single word. If the word turns out to mean `A`, then the result turns in one direction; but if it means `Z`, then it turns in the other direction.

Comment: Thank you. I did not expect that so simple

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few phrases in English which use the metaphor of rotation (usually about an axle or pivot) to stand for choosing options. Presumably the origin is with the (traditional, Libran-style) balance. This is particularly common in the law, for the obvious reason that the law uses this kind of balance as a key metaphor.

Examples include, *turn upon*, *a pivotal moment*, *to hold in the balance*, etc.

So in this case, the presence of the word was somehow sufficiently important that it had it been missing (or *vice versa*), the judgement would have been quite different.

Answer (score -1):

It's generally used as a phrasal verb.

[image: Meaning]

[Dictionary reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/turn+on)

Comment: None of those describe the sense being used in the question.